# PyMongo: How to use a list as a projection in find()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have a collection *coll* and I want to retrieve two fields from this collection using the find() function from the PyMongo library. Let's call these fields *field_1* and *field_2*.

The standard way to do it is:

```
coll.find({}, {'field_1': 1, 'field_2': 1})
```

Now, I have these fields in a list *fields_list*. Is it possible to do something like:

```
coll.find({}, fields_list)
```

I can't find any information in the official documentation and I doubt I'm the first one to think about doing that.

My first guess was to go through the list and create a long string: "field_1: 1, field_2: 1" but this obviously doesn't work because the colon and the "1" shouldn't be in the string for the find() function to understand the query.

Does anyone have any clue on how to use a list in the projection query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try converting the field list to a dict like this:

```
coll.find({}, {field: 1 for field in field_list})
```